# changing the style inside "if" statement

Tags: php, html, css

I was trying to change the style of only a part of php. This is my codes;

```
if($fetch_array)
{
    $foto_destination = $fetch_array['foto'];
echo "<img src = '$foto_destination' height='150px' width='150px'>";
}
else
{



?>
<div style= "position:absolute; left:350px; top:70px;">
<?php
echo "<img src = 'images/avatar_default.png' height='150px' width='150px'>";
?>
</div>
```

But, this php part is inside if. This is why i could not change it? I want to display the image where i define it inside the div tag if the statement of "if" is true. How can i do this? Where am i missing?
Thanks

Comment: Where is the `if`? I can't see it in your code.

Comment: Post your complete code. Where is IF???

Comment: sorry:) Apparently, I could not post

Comment: Do you think there is overwrite or something in somewhere of my whole codes(If i can do that inside is statement.I am new for php and style.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, it should be:

```
<?php

if($fetch_array){
?>
<div style= "position:absolute; left:350px; top:70px;">
<?php
    $foto_destination = $fetch_array['foto'];
    print "  <img src = '$foto_destination' height='150px' width='150px'>";
}else{
?>
<div style= "position:absolute; left:350px; top:70px;">
  <img src = 'images/avatar_default.png' height='150px' width='150px'>
<?php
}
?>

</div>
```

It shows the $foto_destination, if there is one.

HTH

Comment: Yes, you are correct. This way works( if i put it at the top) but what i want using style attribute inside "if" so that i can change it according to the statements.

Comment: Btw, why my codes did not work because if i understand the reason, i will not ask silly question no more.Can not i define div inside "if"?

Comment: I changed it. Did you mean that?

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean like this?

```
<?php
if($fetch_array) {


    $photo = $fetch_array['foto'];
    $styles = 'position:absolute; left:350px; top:70px;';

} else {

    $photo = 'images/avatar_default.png';
    $styles = 'position:absolute; left:350px; top:70px;';

}
?>
<div style="<?php echo $styles; ?>">
<img src="<?php echo $photo; ?>" height="150" width="150" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is correct or you can do an isset()

```
if (isset($fetch_array) {
  ...
```

The only advantage being that it will not error if the variable is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more compact version, shorttags must be enabled.

```
<div style="position:absolute; left:350px; top:70px;">
  <img src="<?= isset($fetch_array['foto']) ? "images/avatar_default.png" : $foto_destination['foto'] ?>" height="150px" width="150px" />
</div>
```

otherwise:

```
<div style="position:absolute; left:350px; top:70px;">
  <img src="<?php echo isset($fetch_array['foto']) ? "images/avatar_default.png" : $foto_destination['foto'] ?>" height="150px" width="150px" />
</div>
```