# add CCS style which depends on php IF statement inside mysqli_fetch_array

Tags: php, css, mysqli

I want to add CCS style which depends on php IF statement. I have found something: [changing the style inside "if" statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170498/changing-the-style-inside-if-statement), but somehow it doesn`t work, maybe because of WHILE statement in my code.

```
<?php
$possible_lang_list = mysqli_query($con, 
'SELECT * FROM page WHERE title = "lang" ORDER BY name1 ASC');

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($possible_lang_list)) {
  echo '
      <div class="language" id="' . $row['name2'] . '">
      <p>' . $row['name1'] . '</p>
      </div>
  ';
}
?>
```

I want to display only div class="language" where $row['name2'] == $x, with possibility to display whole class "language" with JavaScript.  Could anyone help?

I have tried:

```
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($possible_lang_list)) {
  if ($row['name2'] == $x) {
  ?>
  <div style="display:block;">
  <?php } else {
  ?>
  <div style="display:none;">
  <?php
  echo '
      <div class="" id="' . $row['name2'] . '">
        <p>' . $row['name1'] . '</p>

      </div>
  </div>';
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate "somehow it doesn't work"?

Comment: It is displayed only div where $row['name2'] == $x as I want, but it is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now it is working:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($possible_lang_list)) {
  if ($row['name2'] == $x) {
  ?>
  <div style="display:block;">
  <?php } else {
  ?>
  <div style="display:none;">
  <?php   }
  echo '
      <div class="" id="' . $row['name2'] . '">
        <p>' . $row['name1'] . '</p>

      </div>
  </div>';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign a style element with a true/false ternary, like below. Then just output it!

```
<?php

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($possible_lang_list)) {
  $class = ($row['name2'] == $x) ? 'language' : null;
  echo '
      <div class="'.$class.'" id="' . $row['name2'] . '">
      <p>' . $row['name1'] . '</p>
      </div>
  ';
}
```

And then:

Comment: Replace $class with $style

Comment: Why? He said: "I want to display only div class="language" where $row['name2'] == $x"

Comment: You are using two different variables. $style is assigned a value, but the value is never used. $class will always be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($possible_lang_list)) 
{
  if($row['name2'] == $x)
  { 
     echo '<div class="language" id="' . $row['name2'] . '"><p>' . $row['name1'] . '</p>
  </div>';
  }
  else
  {
    echo '<div class="" id="' . $row['name2'] . '"><p>' . $row['name1'] . '</p>
  </div>';
  }
```

}

Hope it will work